# Close dropdown menu after calling the function

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the problem with dropdown menu. When I expand the dropdown menu, all are working as expected. But, there is possibility to disable first search button and disable txtSearch input field? (I mean class `"glyphicon glyphicon-search black-icon"` )?

Also, in the comment, after onSubmit function I can reset all form field by `form.reset()`; there is any possibility to reset one window on form? I thinking about txtSearchCities form control.

Also have problem with automatic close dropdown menu after called onSubmit2 function.

Used technologies: anugar 2, bootstrap 3.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formtag)" #formtag="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch" ngModel name="txtSearch"/>
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit2(formtag2)" #formtag2="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="filter">Cities:</label>
                      <select class="form-control" id="txtSearchCities" ngModel name="txtSearchCities">
                                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>All</option>
                                        <option value="example1">1</option>
                                        <option value="example2">2</option>
                                        <option value="example3">3</option>                         
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="contain">Search</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearchPattern" ngModel name="txtSearchPattern" minlength="3"/>
                    </div>  
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search black-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Function from component:

```
    onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.exampleService.getCities(form.value.txtSearch)
      .subscribe(
          data => {console.log(data)},
          error => console.error(error),
      );

  }

     onSubmit2(form: NgForm) {
    this.exampleService.getCities(form.value.txtSearchPattern+form.value.txtSearchCities)
      .subscribe(
          data => {console.log(data)},
          error => console.error(error),
      );

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send dropdown object to your `onSubmit()` method and there you can remove `open` class from the dropdown object to close it. Sou your html would look like :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formtag,dropdownDiv)" #formtag="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
          <input [disabled]="dropdownDiv.classList.contains('open')" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch" ngModel name="txtSearch"/>
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <div #dropdownDiv class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit2(formtag2)" #formtag2="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="filter">Cities:</label>
                      <select class="form-control" id="txtSearchCities" ngModel name="txtSearchCities">
                                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>All</option>
                                        <option value="example1">1</option>
                                        <option value="example2">2</option>
                                        <option value="example3">3</option>                         
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="contain">Search</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearchPattern" ngModel name="txtSearchPattern" minlength="3"/>
                    </div>  
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search black-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Then your `onSubmit()` would look like this:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm,dd:any) {
    if(dd.classList.contains('open'))
      dd.classList.remove('open');
    this.exampleService.getCities(form.value.txtSearch)
      .subscribe(
          data => {console.log(data)},
          error => console.error(error),
      );
}
```

Comment: it is working fantastic! Thank You. In that same way I can disable first input field, when the dropdown menu was opened?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I have added a part of code to your input. That should disable your input when dropdown is open

Comment: I tried on similar way. But the input tag does not have [enabled] attribute, and when I closed the dropdown menu, the input field is still disabled. To enable it, there I must refresh app or call onSubmit2 function.